# In Scala how to ensure for comprehension iterates through all non empty lists?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have the following two lists , I am not sure if at run time list2 will be empty or full , but list1 will be always non empty, how to ensure that for the following for loop value of list are at least printed

```
val list1 = List(1,2,3)                   //> list1  : List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
val list2 = List()                        //> list2  : List[Nothing] = List()
for( counti <- list1 ; countj <- list2 ) yield println (counti + " - " + countj)
                                                  //> res7: List[Unit] = List()
```

I am expecting something like

```
1 - BLANK
2 - BLANK
3 - BLANK
```

but above for loop is giving me blank results List()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for (
  counti <- list1;
  countj <- if(list2.nonEmpty) list2 else List("BLANK")
) {
  println(counti + " - " + countj)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you don't need `yield` if you're only using the `for` for side effects (printing):

```
for( counti <- list1 ; countj <- list2 )
  println (counti + " - " + countj)
```

Second, what do you expect the value of `countj` to be if you have an empty list? There's no way you can expect the code to work if there's no value for `countj`.

This might do what you want though:

```
// Just print counti
if (list2.isEmpty)
  for( counti <- list1 ) println(counti)
// Print both    
else for ( counti <- list1 ; countj <- list2 )
  println (counti + " - " + countj)
```